# convert text to json with this format

Tags: python, json, file

I need to convert the text file to JSON with this format

```
'annotations': [{u'image_id': 0, u'caption': u'the man is playing a guitar'},
                    {u'image_id': 0, u'caption': u'a man is playing a guitar'},
                    {u'image_id': 1, u'caption': u'a woman is slicing cucumbers'},
                    {u'image_id': 1, u'caption': u'the woman is slicing cucumbers'},
                    {u'image_id': 1, u'caption': u'a woman is cutting cucumbers'}]
    }
```

text file as

```
   image_id 42 caption man is sitting on bench with his head
   image_id 73 caption man is riding motorcycle on the street
   image_id 74 caption cat laying on top of bed next to window
```

the code is

```
import json
images = []
with open('1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        _, image_id, _, caption = line.split(maxsplit=3)
        images.append({"image_id": int(image_id), "caption": caption})

 with open('r.json', "w") as f:
    json.dump(images, f)
```

but got in the result file

```
[{"image_id": 42, "caption": "man is holding an umbrella in the rain\n"}, {"image_id": 73, "caption": "black and white cat sitting on top of car\n"},....]
```

as the problem when i tried to read the result file

```
imgToAnnsRES = {ann['image_id']: [] for ann in datasetRES['annotations']}
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: should `images` be a list of the first mentioned JSON format? is there an example of multiple annotations? what about multiple images?

Comment: please see the edit post

Comment: you should include a part of your text file, because right now it doesn't match

Comment: What's the problem with your current output ? `\n` at the end of caption?

Comment: *where* did you get that?

Comment: i edit the post

Comment: i need to add word(annotations) at the beginning of the list

Comment: Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you got the initial dict:

```
images = [{u'image_id': 0, u'caption': u'the man is playing a guitar'},
                    {u'image_id': 1, u'caption': u'a man is playing a guitar'},
                    {u'image_id': 2, u'caption': u'a woman is slicing cucumbers'},
                    {u'image_id': 3, u'caption': u'the woman is slicing cucumbers'},
                    {u'image_id': 4, u'caption': u'a woman is cutting cucumbers'}]
```

We can simply define the `datasetRES` object as :

```
datasetRES = {'annotations': images}
```

Now you can use the following code:

```
imgToAnnsRES = {ann['image_id']: [] for ann in datasetRES['annotations']}
```